# Libgdx crashes immediately upon opening with Java(TM) Platform SE Binary

Tags: java, libgdx

I am studying a course on Udemy, where we write files using Libgdx.
I downloaded Libgdx, and tried to start it with Java(TM) Platform SE Binary. It opens, but crashes as soon as it opens. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Java and Libgdx repeatedly, ensured that Java is enabled, and even removed security features. Nothing works. Please can someone help?

Comment: Do you mean the setup app crashes, or your game when you first compile and run it?

Comment: The setup app crashes

Comment: Open a command prompt, navigate to the directory with the setup jar and run it using `java -jar setup.jar` using whatever the actual name of the file is. This will at least let you see what the error is.